# a flip-card class is not transforming in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeerror

this code is throwing an Uncaught TypeError.
i am trying to flip a flip-card by clicking on it.
But the code is giving this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined"
what is the problem?
Here i have used named the div i am trying to rotate as "flip-card"
i have also commented the hover attribute in the css property.

CODE:

```js
function rotate_card(){
  console.log("here");
  var j=document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card");
  console.log(j);
  var k=0;
  k += 180;
  j.style.transform = "rotateY(" + k + "deg)";
  //flip.style.transform="rotateY(180deg)";        
}
```

```css
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/*.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}*/

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--[if lt IE 7]>
                <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->

            
            <div class="flip-card" onclick="rotate_card()">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                <h1>palaver</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>babble</h1> 
                <p>talking too much for time pass</p> 
                <p>the audience were really bored so they palavered</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
            <script>
                
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card")` will return an DOM Array elements, just add `[0]` to select the first element of the array, like this:

```js
function rotate_card(){
  var j=document.getElementsByClassName("flip-card")[0];
  var k=0;
  
  if(j.style.transform) {
    k = +j.style.transform.substring(7, j.style.transform.indexOf('deg'));
  }
  console.log(k);
  k += 180;
  j.style.transform = "rotate(" + k + "deg)";
  //flip.style.transform="rotateY(180deg)";        
}
```

```css
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/*.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}*/

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--[if lt IE 7]>
                <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
            <![endif]-->

            
            <div class="flip-card" onclick="rotate_card()">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                <h1>palaver</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>babble</h1> 
                <p>talking too much for time pass</p> 
                <p>the audience were really bored so they palavered</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
            <script>
                
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it is working.
but now if i click it again, it is not rotating back.
any idea how i can achieve that functionality?

Comment: @MahmudMushfique, I updated my code snippet, check it out and voteup and accept please :)

Comment: thanks a ton man!
i accepted the answer. however, I can not upvote as I don't have 15 point :(